# jquery hide/show table / tr questions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table where by each row will have links and there will be a hidden row underneath it which should be opened upon clicking the link

```
<tr>
    <td>
      <a href="" class="link_1">03/09/3012</a>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
        £66.36
    </td>
    <td>
        -£628.74
    </td>
</tr>
<tr style="display:none;" id="desc_1">
    <td colspan="4">
        Housing Benefit Direct
    </td>
</tr>
```

I am looking for the jquery so as any link with the class link_x will toggle the row desc_x

can anyone help please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `id` portion of the class name in the markup:

```
<a href="" class="link">03/09/3012</a>
```

and

```
<tr style="display:none;" class="desc">
```

Then use this JS:

```
$(".link").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents("tr").next("tr").show();
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/3RJJe/2/

Comment: brilliant thanks - how to i make it toggle though as opposed to just opening ?